# On Root `/` Route, show SignUp Page if Unauthenticated otherwise show Dashboard Page if Authenticated in Remix?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, remix.run

Basically, I have 3 pages (or 2 routes) in my Remix app:

1. `/login` - Login
2. `/` - Sign Up (if unauthenticated)
3. `/` - Dashboard (if authenticated)

How do I make sure to show `Dashboard` on `/` route if authenticated & show `Sign Up` if unauthenticated?

[The answer on here](https://github.com/remix-run/remix/discussions/5391) is pretty close but I want to figure out what to do with `Outlet`?

#### root.tsx

```
import type { LinksFunction, LoaderFunctionArgs } from "@remix-run/node"
import {
    Links,
    LiveReload,
    Meta,
    Outlet,
    Scripts,
    ScrollRestoration,
    useLoaderData,
} from "@remix-run/react"

import styles from "./styles/tailwind.css"

export const links: LinksFunction = () => [
    {
        rel: "stylesheet",
        href: styles,
    },
]

export const loader = async ({ request }: LoaderFunctionArgs) => {
    const isAuthenticated = false // getAuthenticatedUser(request)

    if (isAuthenticated) {
        // run code to get user home page data and return a response
        return {
            type: "dashboard",
        }
    }

    // run code to get the public data and return a response
    return {
        type: "signup",
    }
}

const SignUp = () => (
    <>
        <h1>SignUp</h1>
    </>
)

const Dashboard = () => (
    <>
        <h1>Dashboard</h1>
    </>
)

const App = () => {
    const loaderData = useLoaderData<typeof loader>()

    return (
        <html lang="en">
            <head>
                <meta charSet="utf-8" />
                <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
                <Meta />
                <Links />
            </head>
            <body>
                <Outlet />
                {loaderData.type === "signup" ? <SignUp /> : <Dashboard />}
                <ScrollRestoration />
                <Scripts />
                <LiveReload />
            </body>
        </html>
    )
}

export default App
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Mayank gave the answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77846674/6141587) but its a bit confusing as he used different variables so I'm posting it here in detail with filenames similar to the original question.

#### root.tsx

```
import type { LinksFunction } from "@remix-run/node"
import { Links, LiveReload, Meta, Outlet, Scripts, ScrollRestoration } from "@remix-run/react"

import styles from "./styles/tailwind.css"

export const links: LinksFunction = () => [
    {
        rel: "stylesheet",
        href: styles,
    },
]

const App = () => {
    return (
        <html lang="en">
            <head>
                <title>My App</title>
                <meta charSet="utf-8" />
                <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
                <Meta />
                <Links />
            </head>
            <body>
                <Outlet />
                <ScrollRestoration />
                <Scripts />
                <LiveReload />
            </body>
        </html>
    )
}

export default App
```

#### routes/_index.tsx

You can toggle `isAuthenticated` by removing the `!` to see the dashboard page.

```
import { json, type LoaderFunctionArgs } from "@remix-run/node"
import { useLoaderData } from "@remix-run/react"

import Dashboard from "./dashboard"
import SignUp from "./signup"

export const loader = async ({ request }: LoaderFunctionArgs) => {
    const isAuthenticated = !true // getAuthenticatedUser(request)

    return json({
        isAuthenticated,
    })
}

const Home = () => {
    const loaderData = useLoaderData<typeof loader>()

    if (loaderData.isAuthenticated) return <Dashboard />
    return <SignUp />
}

export default Home
```

#### routes/dashboard.tsx

```
const Dashboard = () => (
    <>
        <h1>Dashboard</h1>
    </>
)

export default Dashboard
```

#### routes/signup.tsx

```
const SignUp = () => (
    <>
        <h1>SignUp</h1>
    </>
)

export default SignUp
```

This shows `SignUp` & `Dashboard` page on the same route `/`. The most confusing part to me was `Outlet` but I think removing the code from `root.tsx` into `routes/_index.tsx` solved the problem.

In hindsight, I should've read these 2 things:

1. https://remix.run/docs/en/main/file-conventions/routes
2. https://interactive-remix-routing-v2.netlify.app/

All I needed to understand routing. Makes understanding the above code much simpler.

> **IMPORTANT NOTE:** Make sure to not use `signup.tsx` route if you want the sign up page (and dashboard page) to show up on `/` route itself. Add all your `loaders` & `actions` in the `_index.tsx` route itself otherwise you'll get `405 method not allowed` error that took me a while to figure out.

Answer (score 3):

Loader in Remix runs on the **server side**, so let's say if you hit `/` route on the browser the `request` in the laoder have cookies header where you can store the user's authentication information. There you can write a custom login to check if the user is authenticated or not, and you can return that information.

```
import { json, type LoaderFunctionArgs } from '@remix-run/node';
import {
  useLoaderData,
} from '@remix-run/react';
import Home from 'some_path';
import Login from 'some_path';

export async function loader({ request }: LoaderFunctionArgs) {
  // extract the authentication information from request
  const isAuthenticated = {some_login}
  return json({
    isAuthenticated,
  });
}
```

Also, now you can access the loader data on client side.

```
export default function Component() {
  const {isAuthenticated} = useLoaderData<typeof loader>()

  if (isAuthenticated) return <Home />
  return <Login />
}
```

The above code will be in your `_index.ts` file which will serve as your root route. Now if you are aware of Remix Routing: https://remix.run/docs/en/main/file-conventions/routes
if you create another pages like `/about` or `/stuff`, all of them are by considered as children of `_index.ts` or `/` route. So if someone goes to `/some_route` the loader of the index page is called first and depending on the user authentication they will be routed.

Lastly in the `Home` component simply import Outlet like this:

```
import {
  Outlet,
} from '@remix-run/react';

export default function Home() {
  return <>
  -------------
    <Outlet/>
  -------------
  </>
}
```

The above Outlet will render the child pages

Comment: by `Home` you mean `Dashboard`, right? how will the `Login` page have the html, head tags then? that's my question. because what i can see is your `Home` route is the root route which has `Outlet` & `Login` doesn't have any parent that is wrapped.

Comment: https://github.com/remix-run/remix/discussions/5391#discussioncomment-8182417

Comment: yo thanks, can you check if my answer posted below is correct? it works perfectly but don't know if its buggy. i did check for `title` & it shows correctly too.